# Computing the density of a word in a file using command line

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm trying to find the density of a word by finding the number of lines containing a word and the total number of lines. I tried this:

```
echo $((grep 'word' filename | wc -l)/(wc -l filename))
```

But it's throwing me a syntax error. I'm sure it's something basic, but I'm pretty new so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `$((expr))` for calulations and `$(command)` for subshell; try with `echo $(($(grep 'word' filename | wc -l) / $(wc -l filename) ))`.
Note that without using `bc` you can only use integers.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` and `expr` are the wrong tools.  You want a simple awk script:

```
awk '/word/{count++} END { print count/NR}' input-file
```

Note that you're not even explicitly calling `expr`, but your attempt to use `/` as a division operator implies that is your intent.  But in that context, `/` is integer division, so very likely not what you want.  Using `grep` piped to `wc` will work, but that forces you to read the input mulitple times, which you don't want.  Using awk to scan the file once, counting the lines that match seems like your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

For anyone else who's new and stumbles upon this, from my understanding what this does is counts the number of times a word appears. Then once it reads the entire input, it prints that value / NR (which is the number of records/lines).

Comment: @Taco: it counts the number of lines on which the word appears.  If the word appears multiple times on one line, that line will still only be counted once.

Comment: @Taco, as Chris Dodd points out, this merely counts the number of lines which match the word.  (Perhaps this requirement was influenced by the original attempt to use grep and wc, which makes that an easier metric.) . To count the number of occurrences, you could do something like `awk '/word/{ count += (NF -1)} END { print count/NR}' FS=word input-file`